# sort table based on select options using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement sorting of the table using select options(names/type/doc/date) and click on the button the table should display the sorting result. spent almost a day on this didn't get any idea where am I going wrong. Do I need to call the same function for each of the below options? Please help. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Below is , my code.

```js
(function($) {
  const
    cellValue = (row, index) => index !== -1 ? $(row).children('td').eq(index).text() : 0,
    compareCells = (index, options) =>
      (rowA, rowB) => {
        const colOpts = options[index] || {};
        let
          a = cellValue(rowA, index),
          b = cellValue(rowB, index);
        if (colOpts.dateFormat) {
          a = moment(a, colOpts.dateFormat).valueOf(),
          b = moment(b, colOpts.dateFormat).valueOf()
        }
        return $.isNumeric(a) && $.isNumeric(b) ? a - b : a.toString().localeCompare(b);
      };
  Object.assign($.fn, {
    scanSelectOptionData: function() {
      return [...this.get(0).options].reduce((acc, option, index) => {
        const colOpts = {};
        if (option.dataset.dateFormat) {
          colOpts.dateFormat = option.dataset.dateFormat;
        }
        return { ...acc, [option.value]: colOpts };
      });
    },
    sortTable: function(columnIndex, opts, reverse) {
      let rows = this.find('tbody tr').toArray().sort(compareCells(columnIndex, opts));
      return this.append(reverse ? rows.reverse() : rows);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  const
    $table = $('#myTable'),
    $select = $('#nameselect > select'),
    $radio = $('input[name="sort-direction"]');

  const sortTable = () => {
    const
      columnIndex = parseInt($select.val(), 10),
      opts = $select.scanSelectOptionData(),
      reverse = $('input[name="sort-direction"]:checked').val() === 'DESC';
    $table.sortTable(columnIndex, opts, reverse);
  };

  $select.on('change', sortTable);
  $radio.on('change', sortTable);
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: thin solid grey;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

th, td {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#nameselect, .sort-direction-radio {
  display: inline-flex;
}

#nameselect > select {
  min-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="nameselect">
  <select required>
    <option value="-1">select</option>
    <option value="0">Names</option>
    <option value="1">Type</option>
    <option value="2">Doc</option>
    <option value="3" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY">Date</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="selectlogic" style="display:inline-flex">
  <select required>
    <option>select</option>
    <option value="0">Ascending</option>
    <option value="1">Descending</option>
    
  </select>
</div>

<div class="sort-direction-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="sort-direction" value="ASC" checked />ASC
  <input type="radio" name="sort-direction" value="DESC" />DESC
</div>

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr id="table-header">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Doc</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="">
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>text1</td>
      <td>word</td>
      <td>1/1/21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-type="John">
      <td>John</td>
      <td>text2</td>
      <td>Excel</td>
      <td>31/1/21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-type="Martin">
      <td>Martin</td>
      <td>text3</td>
      <td>pdf</td>
      <td>21/2/21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-type="Rozi">
      <td>Rozi</td>
      <td>text4</td>
      <td>powepoint</td>
      <td>5/10/20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of unnecessary code. If you want to sort the table, just figure out which column index you want to sort. You can assigned column indices as values for the select options.

After you pick a column, determine the sorting direction and any options like special formatting to pre-process the values for sorting. As for date sorting, you will need to parse your dates into `Date` objects or use a library like `moment` (as seen below).

I wrapped the sorting function into a single jQuery plugin called `$.fn.sortTable`.

```js
(function($) {
  const
    cellValue = (row, index) => index !== -1 ? $(row).children('td').eq(index).text() : 0,
    compareCells = (index, options) =>
      (rowA, rowB) => {
        const colOpts = options[index] || {};
        let
          a = cellValue(rowA, index),
          b = cellValue(rowB, index);
        if (colOpts.dateFormat) {
          a = moment(a, colOpts.dateFormat).valueOf(),
          b = moment(b, colOpts.dateFormat).valueOf()
        }
        return $.isNumeric(a) && $.isNumeric(b) ? a - b : a.toString().localeCompare(b);
      };
  Object.assign($.fn, {
    scanSelectOptionData: function() {
      return [...this.get(0).options].reduce((acc, option, index) => {
        const colOpts = {};
        if (option.dataset.dateFormat) {
          colOpts.dateFormat = option.dataset.dateFormat;
        }
        return { ...acc, [option.value]: colOpts };
      });
    },
    sortTable: function(columnIndex, opts, reverse) {
      let rows = this.find('tbody tr').toArray().sort(compareCells(columnIndex, opts));
      return this.append(reverse ? rows.reverse() : rows);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  const
    $table = $('#myTable'),
    $select = $('#nameselect > select'),
    $radio = $('input[name="sort-direction"]');

  const sortTable = () => {
    const
      columnIndex = parseInt($select.val(), 10),
      opts = $select.scanSelectOptionData(),
      reverse = $('input[name="sort-direction"]:checked').val() === 'DESC';
    $table.sortTable(columnIndex, opts, reverse);
  };

  $select.on('change', sortTable);
  $radio.on('change', sortTable);
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: thin solid grey;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

th, td {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#nameselect, .sort-direction-radio {
  display: inline-flex;
}

#nameselect > select {
  min-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<div id="nameselect">
  <select required>
    <option value="-1">select</option>
    <option value="0">Names</option>
    <option value="1">Type</option>
    <option value="2">Doc</option>
    <option value="3" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY">Date</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="sort-direction-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="sort-direction" value="ASC" checked />ASC
  <input type="radio" name="sort-direction" value="DESC" />DESC
</div>

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr id="table-header">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Doc</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="">
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>text1</td>
      <td>word</td>
      <td>1/1/21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-type="John">
      <td>John</td>
      <td>text2</td>
      <td>Excel</td>
      <td>31/1/21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-type="Martin">
      <td>Martin</td>
      <td>text3</td>
      <td>pdf</td>
      <td>21/2/21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-type="Rozi">
      <td>Rozi</td>
      <td>text4</td>
      <td>powepoint</td>
      <td>5/10/20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. is it possible to use buttons instead of a radio-buttons. By default the table should be as it is. only onclick of the button (acs/des) its should perform the logic.

Comment: @user3448925 so you want the button to have a pressed state for ascending, but unpressed for descending? Sounds backwards.

Comment: yes exactly buttons for both ascending and descending. That is the requirement

Comment: Mr. Polymir, is there any way to do with select dropdown, likewise author, names. one more select dropdown which has ascending and descending? updated snippet